# How to pass any hyperlink or div id to another page in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, models

here is my code to display images on the page

```
@foreach (var i in Model)
{
    <li>
        <a href="@i.Image" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" id="@i.Id">
            <img src="@i.Image" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

in this code i want to get the id of clicked image hyperlink on the next page i want to display this image , and some other attributed based on id from database

any suggestions please

Comment: What is the signature of the controller method your redirecting to?

Comment: What is the name of the method? What is the name of the controller? What are its parameters?

Comment: oh! the name of method would be the Details and the name of controller is Admin. and i think according to my need i only need image id to be passed to next page .

Comment: See Shyju's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Url.Action` helper method to build the url to another action method and pass the image id as a querystring parameter.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details","Image",new {imageId=i.Id})" 
                       class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" >
        <img src="@i.Image" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
 </a>
```

When razor executes the above code, It will generate markup like this for the a tag.

```
<a href=/"Image/Details?imageId=123"
```

Where `123` could the id of the image in your loop iteration.

Assuming you have a `Details` action method in your `ImageController` which accepts the image id in a parameter named `imageId`

```
public ActionResult Details(int imageId)
{
  // imageId param will have the id of the clicked image. 
  // you can get the details of the image using the id and return something to the view.
  // To do : Return something
}
```

Comment: so basically at end of Details method it return to  view of the page on which i want to show details on base of id. here i will again use @Url.Action() to pass id to required page and on that page i will get information by GET method to get id from url ?

Comment: Yes. The querystring will have the image id in a parameter called ImageId. In your Details action, read it and using that you can get the details you need from wherever you want (from a db table may be ? ) and return something to the view.

Comment: You need to add the view for the action method. Create a razor view in `~/views/Image`  directory with the name `Details.cshtml` That is basic MVC. I suggest you read MVC tutorials to get an understanding about MVC conventions